# JSP import with dynamic URL

Tags: java, jsp

I am in a situation where I am importing a jsp page which in turn imports two other pages based on the parameters of the import.  The problem is that when I try to use the parameters in the URL of the two imports on the page that is imported, it is an invalid URL. But if I hard code the parameters into the URL it loads with no problem.  This is how my code is:

```
//the following is the first import
<c:import url="/blahblah/index.jsp">
    <c:param name="sectionId" value="3" />
    <c:param name="aPageId" value="5" />
    <c:param name="bPageId" value="2" />
</c:import>

// the following is (index.jsp) the page that is imported and imports other pages based on the parameters

    int sectionId = request.getParameter("sectionId");
    int aPageId = request.getParameter("aPageId");
    int bPageId = request.getParameter("bPageId");

    <c:import url="/blahblah/blah.jsp?sectionId=<%=sectionId%>&page_id=<%=aPageId%>" />

    <c:import url="/blahblah/blah.jsp?sectionId=<%=sectionId%>&page_id=<%=bPageId%>" />
```

Am I outputting the parameters incorrectly? It doesn't work even if I hard code the variables like:

```
int bPageId = 3;
```

It will only work if I actually write 3 in the c:import like this:

```
<c:import url="/blahblah/blah.jsp?sectionId=3&page_id=2" />
```

Comment: `request.getParameter()` return `String` but you assign this to `int`

Comment: Now I will add as answer :-)

Comment: On the very first note, you should avoid using java code in jsp page. Instead use servlets to serve the purpose.

Comment: I added as answer see )

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet, Afsun.     And thank you to Deepika for the advice, but in this situation I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code.In java `request.getParameter(String name)` method returns `String` but in your code you assign it to `int`.You must parse it to `int`

```
    int sectionId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("sectionId"));
    int aPageId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("aPageId"));
    int bPageId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("bPageId"));
```

Comment: Thank you,  do I need to import any specific class to use Integer? because the page isn't loading when I do this.

Comment: No.you do not need any specific import.Because `Integer` is in `java.lang` library and also this library is automatically imported to each java pages.Check other possible errors in your page

Comment: you were right, i had forgotten to write int in front of one of the variable declarations.  I have narrowed the problem down to this:  <c:import url="/blahblah/blah.jsp?sectionId=<%=sectionId%>&page_id=<%=aPageId%>" />

Comment: I am able to output sectionId and aPageId onto the page.. but it is not working the way I am trying to put it in the url=""

Comment: Why you do not use html link?

Comment: html link? i dont understand

Comment: I got it, I set another variable and created the url there then just used that one variable as the url=""  and it worked...   String aURL = /blahblah/blah.jsp?sectionId=" + sectionId + "&page_id=" + aPageId; <c:import url="aURL" />

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped, especially Afsun!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters to a  tag you should practically pass the whole url with parameters, as specified [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_param_tag.htm)

```
//the following is the first import
<c:import url="/blahblah/index.jsp" var="myURL">
    <c:param name="sectionId" value="3" />
    <c:param name="aPageId" value="5" />
    <c:param name="bPageId" value="2" />
</c:import>

// the following is (index.jsp) the page that is imported and imports other pages based on the parameters    
    <c:import url="${myURL}" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't understand, where is myURL set? do I get rid of the params?

Comment: The myURL var is defined in the declaration of the first import url. You don't have to get rid of the params, you just have to put a name(myURL) on your first import url and then simply call that name in your other import url